# spark cassandra connector can't read ssl trust store file present in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hdfs, spark-cassandra-connector, truststore

I am trying to configure SSL between Spark and Cassandra. Passing a local filepath for [trustStore](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-truststore-and-keystore-in-java/#) works, whereas passing [HDFS filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938606/what-is-the-path-to-directory-within-hadoop-filesystem) doesn't work. It throws an error as `File Not Found`, both in [Yarn client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793694/what-is-yarn-client-mode-in-spark) and [cluster mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html).

```java
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", "password");
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", "jks file path");
```

Any idea why does it happen? The same file works through `sc.textfile()`.

```json
Exception:
About to save to Cassandra.16/07/22 08:56:55 ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1469177810000 ms.0 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/abc/ssl.jks (No such file or directory) 
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Thanks
Hema

Answer (score 2):

This happens because SSL parameters are used by Java driver that doesn't know anything about HDFS. You need to put truststore & keystore to every node into the same location, and specify it in [config parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-ssl-connection-options).

I'll flag this issue to developers