# Confusion on HDFS 'pwd' equivalents

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

First, I have read this post:[Is there an equivalent to `pwd` in hdfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539694/is-there-an-equivalent-to-pwd-in-hdfs). It says there is no such 'pwd' in HDFS.

However, as I progressed with the instructions of [Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html), I failed on this command:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
put: 'input': No such file or directory
```

It's weird that I **succeed on this command for the first time** I went through the instructions, but **failed for the second time**. It's also weird that I **succeed on this command on my friends computer**, which has the same system (Ubuntu 14.04) and hadoop version (2.7.1) as mine.

Can anyone explain what happened here? Is there some 'pwd' in HDFS after all?

Comment: About the Current Working Directory question: `hdfs groups` will show you which "user" is used when accessing HDFS - either an admin account (say, `hdfs`) or an end-user account ( say, `johndoe`). The CWD will be `/user/hdfs/` or `/user/johndoe/` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You are trying to run the command `$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input` with user that doesn't exist in the **VM/HDFS**
Let me clearly explain you with the following example in **HDP VM**

```
[root@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client]# bin/hdfs dfs -put /etc/hadoop input
put: `input': No such file or directory
```

Here I executed the command with root user and it didn't exist in the HDP VM. Check in the following command to list the users

```
[root@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client]# hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 8 items
drwxrwx---   - ambari-qa hdfs           0 2015-08-20 08:33 /user/ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x   - guest     guest          0 2015-08-20 08:47 /user/guest
drwxr-xr-x   - hcat      hdfs           0 2015-08-20 08:36 /user/hcat
drwx------   - hive      hdfs           0 2015-09-04 09:52 /user/hive
drwxr-xr-x   - hue       hue            0 2015-08-20 09:05 /user/hue
drwxrwxr-x   - oozie     hdfs           0 2015-08-20 08:37 /user/oozie
drwxr-xr-x   - solr      hdfs           0 2015-08-20 08:41 /user/solr
drwxrwxr-x   - spark     hdfs           0 2015-08-20 08:34 /user/spark
```

In `HDFS`, If you want to `copy` a file and not mentioning the absolute path for destination argument, it will consider `home` of the logged user and place your file there. Here `root` user not found.

Now let's switch to `hive` user and test

```
[root@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client]# su hive
[hive@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client]$ bin/hdfs dfs -put  /etc/hadoop input
[hive@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hive hdfs          0 2015-09-04 10:07 /user/hive/input
```

Yay..Successfully Copied..

Hope it helps..!!!

Comment: It's very clear! However, as a beginer, I wonder how you enter such [root@sandbox hadoop-hdfs-client] environment? I suppose it is not the common linux environment but the one for hadoop

Comment: It is a Hortonworks Hadoop eco system vm with all the set up ready..  This is really good for beginners and you can find more details [here](http://hortonworks.com/hdp/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

It means that we need to move input files to hdfs location.

Suppose you have input file named input.txt and we need to move to HDFS, then follow the below command.
Command: hdfs dfs -put /input_location /hdfs_location

In case no specific directory in HDFS
**hdfs dfs -put /home/Desktop/input.txt /**

In case specific directory in HDFS (**Note: We need to create a directory before proceeding**)

**hdfs dfs -put /home/Desktop/input.txt /MR_input**

After that you can run the examples

bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount /input /output

Here Input and output are the paths which should be in HDFS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know using absolute path is one way to make things work. But what I am confused is why relative path works sometimes but failed another time.