# How to change the HDFS user home directory of the hdfs user?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

To my practise on Hadoop HDFS, I understood that on creating a user say u1 and trying to put a file from the local file system to the HDFS, it searches for the directory `/user/u1` (by default) with write permissions on the HDFS file system.

By default all the users search their (HDFS home)directories in the `/user` directory on the HDFS. My doubt is can I change the default HDFS home directory to `/user` directory from something other.

Also is there any possibility to have different locations for HDFS home directories for different users as we do in the case of Linux users i.e for `user1` the HDFS home directory should be `/home1/user1` and for *`user2` the HDFS home directory should be as `/home2/user2.`

Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HDFS Home Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069568/hdfs-home-directory)

Comment: Sonic, can you provide me a link where step by step procedure is there to rebuild the source such that the required changes would take place as per the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069568/hdfs-home-directory

Comment: take a look at this for eclipse setup http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToSetupYourDevelopmentEnvironment

Answer (score 0):

when we use different user login hue,it will show you different path.just like "hdfs" user login path is "/user/hdfs". so if you know the user info you can control it by yourself such as make directory for user: "/user/{username}"

Answer (score 0):

The `hadoop-env.sh` script that gets ran for your HDFS CLI commands will always pick-up `HADOOP_USER_NAME` for a non-Kerberized cluster.

Therefore, if you are user `foo`, and you added `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=bar` into your `.bashrc`, for example, and did `hdfs dfs -ls`, then it will search for `/user/bar` on HDFS.

You can also "become" any HDFS user at runtime and wipe all of HDFS like so `HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs dfs -rm -R -f -skipTrash /`